# Selecting several buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How can someone select a button (not a radio button or checkbox button) but the whole button that would change then change color?  The idea is that someone would select multiple buttons and then submit them.

Comment: "The idea is that someone would select multiple buttons and then submit them" — That's what checkboxes are designed for.

Comment: Your question need some clarification.

Comment: And you can make a checkbox look like a button if that is the reason you do not want to. And you will not have to keep track of what is clicked

Answer (score 1):

You can still use checkboxes and make then look like buttons. Since you use bootstrap it is pretty easy.

```css
.cb-btn:checked + label {
  background-color: Green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" hidden class="cb-btn"><label class="btn btn-primary" for="cb1">Foo</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="cb2" hidden class="cb-btn"><label class="btn btn-primary" for="cb2">Bar</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="cb3" hidden class="cb-btn"><label class="btn btn-primary" for="cb3">Bacon</label>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For each button, you could add an `onclick` function, which would then change the color of the `button`.

`<button onclick = "document.getElementById("myButton").style.backgroundColor = "blue";">Button</button>`